# Cannot install package in tlmgr

Tags: packages, installing, ctan, tlmgr

```
sudo tlmgr install shading
Password:
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr install: package shading not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

So is there anything I can do so I could install the shading package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/shading) using tlmgr?

Comment: The `shading` package is very old...

Answer (score 4):

The [`shading` package](//ctan.org/pkg/shading) does not form part of the TeX Live distribution, so you can't use `tlmgr` to install/update it. You'll have to

1. [download it](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex209/contrib/shading.zip) manually;
2. unZIP it;
3. [store it in a location where TeX can find it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764); and
4. run `texhash` to add `shading.sty` to your TeX search directory.